# how to create a dynamic list of icons in Element-plus

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, element-ui, element-plus

How to print a list of icons just from an array

for example `[{ name: "edit" }, { name: "settings" }]`

and i get

```
<i-mdi-edit />
<i-mdi-settings />
```

and in the browser it really renders the wanted icon

Answer (score 1):

i used dynamic components

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import {reactive} from 'vue'

let items = reactive([{ name: "edit" }, { name: "settings" }])

</script>

<template>

    <component 
       v-for="(item, i) in items"
       :key="i"
       :is="`i-mdi-${item.name}`"
    >
    </component>

</template>
```